# Инженерный калькулятор на Java

Tags: java

Считывает с файла

- `35*7-8+10/2`
- `sin(x)`
- `cos(y)`
- `asin(8)`
- `acos(3)`

и обрабатывает.

Как корректно все это считать?

Comment: Если у вас в файле могут быть сложные конструкции, то придется написать [парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать готовый каркас - [expressionoasis](http://code.google.com/p/expressionoasis/):

> Основанный на Java расширяемый каркас для оценки выражений (Expression Evaluator). Поддерживает математические, логические, булевы, реляционные и объектные выражения.

А вообще, это надо делать на основе [алгоритма сортировочной станции](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Answer (score 2):

Всмысле, как реализовать?

Гуглите запросы на темы:

- Рекурсивный разбор выражения
- Грамматики
- Обратная польская запись.

Если просто использовать, то наверняка есть какая-нибудь библиотека, я просто не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте методы пакета   `java.lang.Math`