# Обработка операций С++

Tags: c++

Никогда не пробовал такое писать но нужно допустим чтобы пользователь ввел в консоли 5*5 и ему выводился ответ 25
Что мне нужно почитать чтобы такое реализовать?

Comment: Любой парсер, ссылок в гугле много. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842/Парсер-математических-выражений тут собирали ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямолинейный подход для примитивных выражений с целыми числами может выглядеть следующим образом (я написал его минут за 15, как говорится, "на коленках"):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class Eval
{
public:
    Eval( const std::string &s ) : s( s )
    {
    }

    Eval & operator =( const std::string &s )
    {
        Eval::s = s;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator ()() const
    {
        enum class Stage { FIRST_ARGUMENT, OPERATION, SECOND_ARGUMENT, TAIL } stage;
        int result = 0;

        try
        {
            size_t n;

            stage = Stage::FIRST_ARGUMENT;
            int x = std::stoi( s, &n );

            stage = Stage::OPERATION;
            const char *p;

            n = s.find_first_not_of( " \t", n );

            if ( n == std::string::npos || !( p = std::strchr( op, s[n] ) ) ) throw std::exception();

            stage = Stage::SECOND_ARGUMENT;

            std::string t = s.substr( ++n );

            int y = std::stoi( t, &n );

            stage = Stage::TAIL;

            n = t.find_first_not_of( " \t", n );

            if ( n != std::string::npos ) throw std::exception();

            switch ( *p )
            {
                case '+': result = x + y; break;
                case '-': result = x - y; break;
                case '*': result = x * y; break;
                case '/':
                    if ( y == 0 )
                    {
                        stage = Stage::SECOND_ARGUMENT;
                        throw std::exception();
                    }
                    result = x / y; break;
                case '$':
                    if ( y == 0 )
                    {
                        stage = Stage::SECOND_ARGUMENT;
                        throw std::exception();
                    }
                    result = x % y; break;
            }                                        
        }
        catch ( const std::exception &ex )
        {
            switch ( stage )
            {
                case Stage::FIRST_ARGUMENT:
                    throw std::invalid_argument( "Error: first operand is invalid." );
                    break;
                case Stage::OPERATION:
                    throw std::invalid_argument( "Error: invalid operation." );
                    break;
                case Stage::SECOND_ARGUMENT:
                    throw std::invalid_argument( "Error: second argument is invalid." );
                    break;
                case Stage::TAIL:
                    throw std::invalid_argument( "Error: redundant symbols in the tail of the expression" );
                    break;
            }
        }                

        return result;                        
    }

 private:
    std::string s;
    const char *op = "+-*/$";
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::string s = "5 * 5";

        std::cout << s << " = " << Eval( s )() << std::endl;

        s = "5 * 5.0";
        std::cout << s << " = " << Eval( s )() << std::endl;
    }
    catch ( const std::invalid_argument &ex )
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
5 * 5 = 25
Error: redundant symbols in the tail of the expression
```

Конечно вы могли бы заменить целые числа на числа с плавающей запятой.

Но в общем случае вам придется писать свой парсер, так как, например, выражение

```
5 * - 5
```

должно распознаваться как корректное.

Вы можете почитать об особенностях парсеров различных языков программирования на моей персональной страничке [здесь](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-20-0) и [здесь](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-9-0-00000001-000-0-0-1444910141)

В своей книге по C++ "Практика применения C++" Страуструп рассматривает построение калькулятора, который позволяет использовать выражения. Думаю, вам следует начать именно со знакомства этого раздела его книги.

Answer (score 3):

Для вычисления арифметических выражений можно воспользоваться алгоритмом [Обратная польская нотация](http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/revpn.php). Для более сложных случаев ознакомьтесь с [Разбор выражений. Компиляторы и интерпретаторы.](http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/index.php)