# Как правильно обработать порядок арифметических операций?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Делаю что-то вроде обработчика выражений, как в Excel...

Есть входящая строка `String inputStr = "5+5-10/8+8*2"` (любые числа и действия).

Как реализовать приоритет действий? Нужен алгоритм.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479204/190934 - на с++

Comment: Еще почитайте про обратную польскую запись http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/revpn.php  может этот подход будет интересней. А вообще замечу, что кроме приоритетов есть понятие ассоциативности операторов - это вкаком порядке выполнять равноприоритетные операторы, в компиляторах языков это учитывается, для калькуляторов может особо и не нужно

Comment: Зацените [вот это](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_сортировочной_станции).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта задача решается с использованием стека через формирование и подсчёт [Обратной Польской Нотации](http://habrahabr.ru/post/100869/) .

Comment: Не люблю её. Бесполезная штука...

Comment: Но минус не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy я уже заметил что тут минусы просто так сыпятся). А чем плоха PRN? Я просто других способов и не знаю если честно, а этот довольно часто встречается.

Comment: Обычный обход и построение дерева, а то и сразу вычисление.

Answer (score 3):

вот решение Обратной Польской Нотации, должно работать проверьте.

```
       import java.util.LinkedList;
       public class Calc {
static boolean isDelim(char c) {
        return c == ' ';
}
static boolean isOperator(char c) {
    return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%' || c == ','|| c == '^';
}
static int priority(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;
                    case ',':
            return 3;
                    case '^':
            return 4;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
static void processOperator(LinkedList<Double> st, char op) {
    Double r = st.removeLast();
    Double l = st.removeLast();
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            st.add(l + r);
            break;
        case '-':
            st.add(l - r);
            break;
        case '*':
            st.add(l * r);
            break;
        case '/':
            st.add(l / r);
            break;
        case '%':
            st.add(l % r);
                            break;
                    case ',':
            st.add(l - r);
            break;
                    case '^':
            st.add(Math.pow(l, r));
            break;
    }
}
public static Double eval(String s) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == '-'){
            String buffer = s;
            s ="0 ";
            s+=buffer;
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '(' && s.charAt(i+1) == '-'){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        sb.replace(i, i+2, "(0 - ");
        s = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
        }
        }

    LinkedList<Double> st = new LinkedList<Double>();
    LinkedList<Character> op = new LinkedList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (isDelim(c))
            continue;
        if (c == '(')
            op.add('(');
        else if (c == ')') {
            while (op.getLast() != '(')
                processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
            op.removeLast();
        } else if (isOperator(c)) {
            while (!op.isEmpty() && priority(op.getLast()) >= priority(c))
                processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
            op.add(c);
        } else {
            String operand = "";
            while (i < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) || i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == '.')
                operand += s.charAt(i++);
            --i;
            st.add(Double.parseDouble(operand));
        }
    }
    while (!op.isEmpty())
        processOperator(st, op.removeLast());
    return st.get(0);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String exp = "12+3.6";
    System.out.println(eval(exp));
    String exp2 = "105 - 1";
    System.out.println(eval(exp2));
            String exp3 = "-105 - 1";
    System.out.println(eval(exp3));
            String exp4 = "(-105 - 1)";
    System.out.println(eval(exp4));
            String exp5 = "-2*(-2)";
    System.out.println(eval(exp5));


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

порядок арифметических операций (приоритет) определяется скобками, например:

```
5+5*5=30

5+(5*5)=30

(5+5)*5=50
```

Comment: не может быть, кэп..

Comment: чего не может быть?

Comment: прочитайте внимательно вопрос...