# Как превратить String выражение в double JAVA?

Tags: java, строки, double

У меня есть `String` переменная, которая содержит выражение `"Math.sqrt(x) + y"`.

x и y вводятся с клавиатуры. Надо подставить значения x и y в выражение и результат засунуть в `double` переменную.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Для этого вам не нужен парсер double, а нужен обработчик математике кого выражение

Comment: проверьте это. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479204/182317 то самое что вам нужно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479204/182317

Comment: @StupakovKirill: Кирилл, ваш ответ состоял только из ссылки на другой ответ, поэтому я преобазовал его в комментарий. Вы имели в виду, что в том ответе есть решение для вашего вопроса?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно Вы имели в виду именно [это](http://slovesnov.users.sourceforge.net/index.php?parser,russian#java)

В общем, вот готовое решение, единственное, надо пересмотреть класс ExpressionEstimator и изменить логику корня квадратного, т.к. выражение Math.sqrt(x) там заменено на sqrt(x). Я не являюсь [автором](http://slovesnov.users.sourceforge.net/index.php?author,russian) этого кода, просто подогнал его класс под ответ.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import stackoverflow.ExpressionEstimator;

public class Task1 {
private static String formula = "sqrt(x) + y";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String x = scanner.nextLine();
        String y = scanner.nextLine();
        formula = formula.replace("x", x);
        formula = formula.replace("y", y);
        System.out.println(formula);
        double v = ExpressionEstimator.calculate(formula);
        System.out.println(v);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

}




public class ExpressionEstimator {

private enum OPERATOR {
    PLUS, MINUS, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE, LEFT_BRACKET, RIGHT_BRACKET, LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET, RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET, LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET, RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET, COMMA, SIN, COS, TAN, COT, SEC, CSC, ASIN, ACOS, ATAN, ACOT, ASEC, ACSC, SINH, COSH, TANH, COTH, SECH, CSCH, ASINH, ACOSH, ATANH, ACOTH, ASECH, ACSCH, RANDOM, CEIL, FLOOR, ROUND, ABS, EXP, LOG, SQRT, POW, ATAN2, MIN, MAX, X, NUMBER, UNARY_MINUS, END
}

private enum CONSTANT_NAME {
    PI, E, SQRT2, SQRT1_2, LN2, LN10, LOG2E, LOG10E
}

private static final double CONSTANT_VALUE[] = { Math.PI, Math.E, Math.sqrt(2), Math.sqrt(.5), Math.log(2),
        Math.log(10), 1. / Math.log(2), 1. / Math.log(10) };

private Node root = null;
private byte[] expression;
private double tokenValue;
private OPERATOR operator;
private int position;
private double[] argument;
private int arguments;

private class Node {
    OPERATOR operator;
    double value;
    Node left, right;

    private void init(OPERATOR operator, double value, Node left) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
    }

    Node(OPERATOR operator, Node left) {
        init(operator, 0, left);
    }

    Node(OPERATOR operator) {
        init(operator, 0, null);
    }

    Node(OPERATOR operator, double value) {
        init(operator, value, null);
    }

    double calculate() throws Exception {
        double x;
        switch (operator) {

        case NUMBER:
            return value;

        case PLUS:
            return left.calculate() + right.calculate();

        case MINUS:
            return left.calculate() - right.calculate();

        case MULTIPLY:
            return left.calculate() * right.calculate();

        case DIVIDE:
            return left.calculate() / right.calculate();

        case UNARY_MINUS:
            return -left.calculate();

        case SIN:
            return Math.sin(left.calculate());

        case COS:
            return Math.cos(left.calculate());

        case TAN:
            return Math.tan(left.calculate());

        case COT:
            return 1 / Math.tan(left.calculate());

        case SEC:
            return 1 / Math.cos(left.calculate());

        case CSC:
            return 1 / Math.sin(left.calculate());

        case ASIN:
            return Math.asin(left.calculate());

        case ACOS:
            return Math.acos(left.calculate());

        case ATAN:
            return Math.atan(left.calculate());

        case ACOT:
            return Math.PI / 2 - Math.atan(left.calculate());

        case ASEC:
            return Math.acos(1 / left.calculate());

        case ACSC:
            return Math.asin(1 / left.calculate());

        case SINH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return (Math.exp(x) - Math.exp(-x)) / 2;

        case COSH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return (Math.exp(x) + Math.exp(-x)) / 2;

        case TANH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return (Math.exp(2 * x) - 1) / (Math.exp(2 * x) + 1);

        case COTH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return (Math.exp(2 * x) + 1) / (Math.exp(2 * x) - 1);

        case SECH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return 2 / (Math.exp(x) + Math.exp(-x));

        case CSCH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return 2 / (Math.exp(x) - Math.exp(-x));

        case ASINH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log(x + Math.sqrt(x * x + 1));

        case ACOSH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log(x + Math.sqrt(x * x - 1));

        case ATANH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log((1 + x) / (1 - x)) / 2;

        case ACOTH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log((x + 1) / (x - 1)) / 2;

        case ASECH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log((1 + Math.sqrt(1 - x * x)) / x);

        case ACSCH:
            x = left.calculate();
            return Math.log(1 / x + Math.sqrt(1 + x * x) / Math.abs(x));

        case RANDOM:
            return Math.random();

        case CEIL:
            return Math.ceil(left.calculate());

        case FLOOR:
            return Math.floor(left.calculate());

        case ROUND:
            return Math.round(left.calculate());

        case ABS:
            return Math.abs(left.calculate());

        case EXP:
            return Math.exp(left.calculate());

        case LOG:
            return Math.log(left.calculate());

        case SQRT:
            return Math.sqrt(left.calculate());

        case POW:
            return Math.pow(left.calculate(), right.calculate());

        case ATAN2:
            return Math.atan2(left.calculate(), right.calculate());

        case MIN:
            return Math.min(left.calculate(), right.calculate());

        case MAX:
            return Math.max(left.calculate(), right.calculate());

        case X:
            return argument[(int) value];

        default:
            throw new Exception("Node.calculate error");
        }
    }
}

private boolean isLetter() {
    return Character.isLetter(expression[position]);
}

private boolean isDigit() {
    return Character.isDigit(expression[position]);
}

private boolean isPoint() {
    return expression[position] == '.';
}

private boolean isFunctionSymbol() {
    byte c = expression[position];
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_';
}

private void getToken() throws Exception {
    int i;

    if (position == expression.length - 1) {
        operator = OPERATOR.END;
    } else if ((i = "+-*/()[]{},".indexOf(expression[position])) != -1) {
        position++;
        operator = OPERATOR.values()[i];
    } else if (isLetter()) {
        for (i = position++; isFunctionSymbol(); position++)
            ;
        String token = new String(expression, i, position - i);
        ;

        try {
            if (token.charAt(0) == 'X' && token.length() == 1) {
                throw new Exception("unknown keyword");
            } else if (token.charAt(0) == 'X' && token.length() > 1 && Character.isDigit(token.charAt(1))) {
                i = Integer.parseInt(token.substring(1));
                if (i < 0) {
                    throw new Exception("index of 'x' should be nonnegative integer number");
                }
                if (arguments < i + 1) {
                    arguments = i + 1;
                }
                operator = OPERATOR.X;
                tokenValue = i;
            } else {
                operator = OPERATOR.valueOf(token);
                i = operator.ordinal();
                if (i < OPERATOR.SIN.ordinal() || i > OPERATOR.MAX.ordinal()) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException _ex) {
            try {
                tokenValue = CONSTANT_VALUE[CONSTANT_NAME.valueOf(token).ordinal()];
                operator = OPERATOR.NUMBER;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                throw new Exception("unknown keyword");
            }
        }
    } else if (isDigit() || isPoint()) {
        for (i = position++; isDigit() || isPoint() || expression[position] == 'E'
                || expression[position - 1] == 'E' && "+-".indexOf(expression[position]) != -1; position++)
            ;

        tokenValue = Double.parseDouble(new String(expression, i, position - i));
        operator = OPERATOR.NUMBER;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("unknown symbol");
    }

}

public void compile(String expression) throws Exception {
    position = 0;
    arguments = 0;
    String s = expression.toUpperCase();// for OPERATOR.valueof()

    String from[] = { " ", "\t" };
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
        s = s.replace(from[i], "");
    }
    this.expression = (s + '\0').getBytes();

    getToken();
    if (operator == OPERATOR.END) {
        throw new Exception("unexpected end of expression");
    }
    root = parse();
    if (operator != OPERATOR.END) {
        throw new Exception("end of expression expected");
    }

}

private Node parse() throws Exception {
    Node node = parse1();
    while (operator == OPERATOR.PLUS || operator == OPERATOR.MINUS) {
        node = new Node(operator, node);
        getToken();
        if (operator == OPERATOR.PLUS || operator == OPERATOR.MINUS) {
            throw new Exception("two operators in a row");
        }
        node.right = parse1();
    }
    return node;
}

private Node parse1() throws Exception {
    Node node = parse2();
    while (operator == OPERATOR.MULTIPLY || operator == OPERATOR.DIVIDE) {
        node = new Node(operator, node);
        getToken();
        if (operator == OPERATOR.PLUS || operator == OPERATOR.MINUS) {
            throw new Exception("two operators in a row");
        }
        node.right = parse2();
    }
    return node;
}

private Node parse2() throws Exception {
    Node node;
    if (operator == OPERATOR.MINUS) {
        getToken();
        node = new Node(OPERATOR.UNARY_MINUS, parse3());
    } else {
        if (operator == OPERATOR.PLUS) {
            getToken();
        }
        node = parse3();
    }
    return node;
}

private Node parse3() throws Exception {
    Node node;
    OPERATOR open;

    if (operator.ordinal() >= OPERATOR.SIN.ordinal() && operator.ordinal() <= OPERATOR.MAX.ordinal()) {
        int arguments;
        if (operator.ordinal() >= OPERATOR.POW.ordinal() && operator.ordinal() <= OPERATOR.MAX.ordinal()) {
            arguments = 2;
        } else {
            arguments = operator == OPERATOR.RANDOM ? 0 : 1;
        }

        node = new Node(operator);

        getToken();
        open = operator;
        if (operator != OPERATOR.LEFT_BRACKET && operator != OPERATOR.LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET
                && operator != OPERATOR.LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET) {
            throw new Exception("open bracket expected");
        }
        getToken();

        if (arguments > 0) {
            node.left = parse();

            if (arguments == 2) {
                if (operator != OPERATOR.COMMA) {
                    throw new Exception("comma expected");
                }
                getToken();
                node.right = parse();
            }
        }
        checkBracketBalance(open);
    } else {
        switch (operator) {

        case X:
        case NUMBER:
            node = new Node(operator, tokenValue);
            break;

        case LEFT_BRACKET:
        case LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET:
        case LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET:
            open = operator;
            getToken();
            node = parse();
            checkBracketBalance(open);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Exception("unexpected operator");
        }

    }
    getToken();
    return node;
}

private void checkBracketBalance(OPERATOR open) throws Exception {
    if (open == OPERATOR.LEFT_BRACKET && operator != OPERATOR.RIGHT_BRACKET
            || open == OPERATOR.LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET && operator != OPERATOR.RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET
            || open == OPERATOR.LEFT_CURLY_BRACKET && operator != OPERATOR.RIGHT_CURLY_BRACKET) {
        throw new Exception("close bracket expected or another type of close bracket");
    }
}

public double calculate(double[] x) throws Exception {
    this.argument = x;
    return calculate();
}

public double calculate() throws Exception {
    if (root == null) {
        throw new Exception("using of calculate() without compile()");
    }
    int length = argument == null ? 0 : argument.length;
    if (length != arguments) {
        throw new Exception("invalid number of expression arguments");
    }
    return root.calculate();
}

/**
 * 
 * @return number of expression arguments
 */
public int getArguments() {
    return arguments;
}

public static double calculate(String s) throws Exception {
    ExpressionEstimator estimator = new ExpressionEstimator();
    estimator.compile(s);
    estimator.argument = null;// clear all arguments
    return estimator.calculate();
}

}
```

Comment: Готово и проверено. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Может быть попробовать [Nashorn](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA_JavaScript%29) если есть возможность писать выражения на Javascript?

(Nashorn — движок JavaScript на языке Java, доступен начиная с Java 8).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Дело в том что Nashorn уже встроен в Java начиная с Java 8 и это возможно позволит справиться с задачей без сторонних библиотек

Comment: @PavelVasilchenko: стоило сразу уточнить, а то ответ выглядел, как предложение использовать JS вместо Java. Добавил ссылку и краткую подсказку, чтобы было понятнее.

Answer (score 0):

как то так
    Double.parseDouble("2.0");

Comment: Пробовал. так работает только если в String записано единственное число. А у меня выражение

Comment: так распарсите всё выражение

Comment: String a = "Math.sqrt(25) - 0.3";
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(a));
не работает

Comment: ещё раз повторяю -вам надо парсить каждый аргумент, можно через nextDouble, можно через регулярки. Math.sqrt(25)  + Double.parseDouble("3.0");

Comment: Дело в том, что строка с выражением тоже вводится, поэтому я не могу просто запарсить 2 числа и подставить их в выражение

Comment: Сами же пишите есть строка... х и у вводятся ... Если и выражение вводится, так бы и написали. Жава готового парсера формул не предоставляет. Разрабатывайте сами или ищите в интернете готовое решение. Если формулу не обязательно записывать на Java, то может быть проще будет воспользоваться встроенным javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в таком случае было бы удобно получать значения через метод

```
java.util.Scanner.nextDouble()
```

А уже затем подставлять их в строку конкатенацией.

Comment: Дело в том, что строка с выражением тоже вводится, поэтому я не могу просто запарсить 2 числа и подставить их в выражение