# Конвертирование String в функцию java.util.function

Tags: java, алгоритм

Вот фрагмент кода в котором задан конструктор, принимающий функциональный интерфейс, принимающий и возвращающий Double. Можно вместо параметра f вводить конвертированый func?

```
 String func;
 public Plot(java.util.function.Function<Double, Double> f) {

    }
```

Comment: Не совсем понял что тебе нужно. Стрингу конвертировать в double можно через Double.valueOf. Или у тебя есть строка кода и тебе ее надо преобразовать в выполнимую функцию?

Comment: Во-первых, в Java нет функций. Во-вторых, в этом фрагменте кода показан конструктор, принимающий _функциональный интерфейс_, принимающий и возвращающий `Double`, а не то, что вы описали. В-третьих, Java - это язык со строгой статической типизацией, а потому простых способов создавать классы в рантайме нет. Опишите подробней чего именно хотите добиться.

Comment: @DaniilMotsniy опишите, что вы хотите получить, если это конечный набор шаблонов функций, то да это реализуемо.

Comment: @DaniilMotsniy Парсим строку для получения атомарных операций -> накапливаем функционал -> получаем функцию.

Comment: Набор функций которые можно записать в виде строки. К примеру, x^2, x^2-6 и т.д.  Достаточно линейных и степенных функций.

Comment: Можно использовать скриптовые языки поверх Java: Lua, Js, Groovy. Этот вариант самый близкий к твоим хотелкам.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нет функций - что вы имеете в виду? Я например часто называю методы функциями, люди иногда так легче воспринимают

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець зря вы это делаете. Легче такое воспринимают те люди, которые плохо понимают Java. А потом из этого непонимания и неправильно выбранной терминологии вырастают неправильные подходы к решению задач.

Comment: Боюсь, что простого способа нет. Вам понадобится парсер математических выражений. Можете посмотреть реализацию здесь: [Как превратить String выражение в double JAVA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479462/) или похожий вопрос на английском: [How to convert a string to a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207447/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-lambda-expression/32682025). Там предлагают использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/greenjoe/lambdaFromString), которая вроде делает то, что Вам нужно, либо использовать встроенный Nashorn.

Comment: @default locale спасибо, попробую