# Задать приоритет операций на С++

Tags: c++

Дано выражение a * (-b) - (c + d / e ) ^ s. a, b, c, d, e, s вводятся с клавиатуры, потом вводишь приоритет для каждой операции. Например для операции "-" установить приоритет 1, и нужно сначала выполнить действия где стоит минус и т.д.

Comment: Раз нужно, почему вы не сделаете?

Comment: Найдите дубликат, кто-нибудь!

Comment: А вообще, [вам сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7).

Comment: @VladD дубликат непойми чего?

Comment: @alexolut: Дубилкат любого вопроса с разбором арифметических выражений? Алгоритм сортировочной станции позволяет иметь различные приоритеты.

Comment: @VladD [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/176217) пойдет?

Comment: @alexolut: Вполне.