# Как из строки построить дерево операций?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, польская-запись

Есть на входе строка, допустим известное `char expr="2+2*2"` которое должно дать 6.

Допустим определены операции `enum operations { opadd = 1 , opmul = 2 , opconst = 3 };`

Тогда можно определить дерево `struct optree { operations op, int arg1, int arg2};`  такой структурой (или другой).

Для 2+2*2 получится такой массив:

`{/*0*/opadd,1,2},{/*1*/opconst,2,0},{/*2*/opmull,3,4},{/*3*/opconst,2,0 },{/*4*/opconst,2,0}`

Обработать массив не получится сразу, его нужно как-то отсортировать что б *приоритет умножения* стал выше, т.е. массив станет таким (теоретически)

`{/*0*/opconst,2,0},{/*1*/opconst,2,0},{/*2*/opconst,2,0},{/*3*/opmul,1,2},{/*4*/opadd,0,1}`
Т.е. получили фактически байт-код, выполняя который последовательно можно получить 6.

Где об этом можно почитать, как эту задачу можно решить?

Comment: Читать об этом "The Dragon Book"

Comment: Мне кажется тут достаточно [алгоритма вычисления обратной польской записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul класс, спасибо, вот https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 ещё есть прямо ответы

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос с хорошими ответами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/17974

Answer (score 0):

Данное преобразование называется *Обра́тная по́льская нота́ция* (или обратная польская запись) — форма записи математических и логических выражений, в которой операнды расположены перед знаками операций.

Сегодня похожая форма используется в [Java-байткоде](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings), [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)(c#) байткоде и [AS3](http://konghack.com/content/19-avm2instructions) (adobe flash) байткоде .

Ссылки [Обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) и её [реализация](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Пример из википедии

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STKDPTH 32 /* Глубина стека */

/* Значения, возвращаемые функцией parse */
#define VAL  0  /* В стек занесено новое значение */
#define ADD  1  /* Сложение */
#define SUB  2  /* Вычитание */
#define MUL  3  /* Умножение */
#define DIV  4  /* Деление */
#define SOF -1  /* Переполнение стека */
#define SUF -2  /* В стеке недостаточно операндов */
#define UNK -3  /* Неопознанное значение */

/* Глобальные переменные */
int scount;
double stack[STKDPTH];

/* Функция распознавания аргументов */
int parse(char *);

/* Точка входа */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Организуем цикл для перебора аргументов командной строки */
    while (*++argv) {

        /* Пытаемся распознать текущий аргумент как число или
         * символ арифметической операции */
        switch (parse(*argv)) {
            case VAL: continue;

            /* Вычисляем */
            case ADD:
                stack[scount - 1] += stack[scount];
                break;

            case SUB:
                stack[scount - 1] -= stack[scount];
                break;

            case MUL:
                stack[scount - 1] *= stack[scount];
                break;

            case DIV:
                if (stack[scount] != 0) {
                    stack[scount - 1] /= stack[scount];
                    break;
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Деление на ноль!\n");
                    return(1);
                }

            /* Обработка ошибок */
            case SUF:
                fprintf(stderr, "Недостаточно операндов!\n");
                return(1);

            case SOF:
                fprintf(stderr, "Переполнение стека!\n");
                return(1);

            case UNK:
                fprintf(stderr, "Неопознанный аргумент!\n");
                return(1);
        }
    }

    /* Вывести результат */
    auto int i;
    for (i = 0; i < scount; i++) printf("%0.3f\n", stack[i]);

    return(0);
}

int parse(char *s)
{
    double tval = 0;
    char * endptr;

    /* Распознаем знаки арифметических операций */
    switch (*s) {
        case '-':
            /* Если минус является первым и не последним символом аргумента,
             * значит пользователь ввел отрицательное число и опознавать его
             * как операцию вычитания не нужно */
            if (*(s+1) != '\0') break;
            if (scount >= 2) {
                scount -= 1;
                return(SUB);
            }
            else return(SUF);

        case '+':
            if (scount >= 2) {
                scount -= 1;
                return(ADD);
            }
            else return(SUF);

        case 'x':
            if (scount >= 2) {
                scount -= 1;
                return(MUL);
            }
            else return(SUF);

        case '/':
            if (scount >= 2) {
                scount -= 1;
                return(DIV);
            }
            else return(SUF);
    }

    errno = 0;

    /* Пытаемся сконвертировать строковый аргумент в число */
    tval = strtod(s, &endptr);

    /* Вернуть ошибку `неопознанный аргумент' в случае неудачи */
    if (errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0') return(UNK);

    /* Проверяем, есть ли свободное место в стеке
     * и сохраняем в нем операнд, иначе возвращаем ошибку переполнения */
    if (scount < STKDPTH) stack[scount++] = tval;
    else return(SOF);

    return(VAL);
}
```

Comment: Тут в гугле нету приорита операций. Возможно кто-нибудь опубликует решение с приоритетом.