# Ввод формулы с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть фиксированное количество переменных, именно 3 штуки, значение которых я знаю. Задача состоит в том, чтобы пользователь вводил с клавиатуры некоторую формулу и программа уже считала значение по ней.

**Например** известен ***x*** = 1 и ***y*** = 2; Пользователь вводит формулу x + y - 2 * x. И программа забивает данные в эту формулу и считает результат.

Подскажите как можно реализовать, предполагал сделать всё через массив char, но встал в ступор и не знаю от чего отталкиваться.

Comment: Выполнить синтаксический анализ введенной строки. Простейший калькулятор такого рода есть в книге Страуструпа [*Программирование: принципы и практика с использованием C++*](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1949-6.html)

Comment: Поищите, тут у нас были пачки парсеров формул. Да, вам придётся написать парсер.

Comment: Вот, например, кандидат в дубликаты: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/10105