# Чтение из файла математической функции с++

Tags: c++, файлы

Необходимо из файла считать вот такие функции. Либо это садизм какой-то либо я не понимаю как это сделать. Необходимо использовать с++.

```
x001 sin(x002) cos(x003) tg(x004) x001x005
tg(x001) sin(x002)cos(x005) 3
x001x003^2 sin(x004)^3 7
cos(x001)^2 x003 ctg(x005) -1
(x003*x005)^2 sin(x001^3) 3
```

Comment: Прочитать не штука, ifstream решит все это. Вопрос, что с этого хочется получить.

Comment: @KoVadim cos из файла функции = cos внутри программы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то `xYYY` - это подставляемые в функции переменные, заданные в коде, а вам нужно считать значения функций для этих аргументов.

В таком случае я бы делал так:

1) Считывал файл полностью в `std::string`

2) С помощью `<regexp>` заменял бы `x([0-9]{3})` на соответствующее значение переменной в коде, `(...)^(...)` на `std::pow($1,$2)`, `x([0-9]{3})x([0-9]{3})` на `x([0-9]{3})*x([0-9]{3})` и т.д. все нужные операции.

3) Разделил бы полученную строку по вайтспейсу (в примере это пробел и перевод строки) на строки.

4) Парсил бы полученные строки в математические записи с помощью каких-нибудь стандартных методов (пример: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Comment: Скорее всего вид будет такой. Вместо X001 к примеру будет стоять 1, а где cos(x002) будет стоять cos(2). Это будет храниться в файле. Это надо будет считать в программу и рассчитать.

Comment: А что такое рассчитать? тут у меня фантазия разрывается. И хорошо бы рассказать, что это "x001x005" - умножение двух переменных или одна такая.

Comment: @KoVadim я сам не понимаю. Попросили курсовой в универ сделать. Скинули файл такой. И попросили его спарсить и написать код решения нелинейных уравнений методом "Моментов". Я сколько в интернете не ищу не могу найти этот метод. А что с этим файлом делать. В упор не представляю. Это просто какой-то садизм. Постараюсь узнать более подробно. Либо идут они....

Comment: @KoVadim. там где стоит просто пробел это "+". x001x005 означает умножение. 1 уровнение имеет вид тогда такой x001+sin(x002)+cos(003)+tg(x004)+x001*x005=B1. Причем может быть x001 до x999