# как убрать кавычки

Tags: c++

Допустим нужно ввести строку 
Например : ((1&1)^(0|1))
Чтобы он вывел : 0
нужно превратить это "((1&1)^(0|1))"
в это ((1&1)^(0|1))

Comment: [Парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/317064)

Comment: Найдете  в программах калькуляторов

Comment: "Как убрать кавычки" - вот как это называется..