# Парсер логических выражений

Tags: node.js, парсер, логические-выражения

Есть выражения вида `(field1:value1"AND"field2:value2)"OR"field3:value2`. Выражения могут быть и сложенее, их нужно привести к объекту вида

```
{
    OR: {
        AND: {
            field1:value1,
            field2:value2
        },
        field3:value3
    }
}
```

Как это лучше организовать? Может есть модуль?

Comment: Не совсем понял, почему or выступает как операнд (?) and

Comment: @СергейКоновалов Перепутал

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно представить строку в виде обратной польской нотации.

операнд1 операнд 2 and операнд 3 or

Это такая запись, когда сначала идут операнды, потом знак операции.  После этого вы сможете пройти задом наперед и разбить польскую нотацию в том виде, который вам нужен.

Преобразование в польскую нотацию происходит при помощи стека. Идете по выражению, заносите операнд в стек, ищите второй операнд, его тоже в стек, потом в стек операцию над ними