# Вычисление простых логических выражений заданных в виде строки

Tags: c++

**Задача:**

*Разработать программу, которая рекурсивно по заданному простому_логическому выражению, вычисляет значение этого выражения.
простое_логическое::=   TRUE | FALSE | NOT простое_логическое |
(простое_логическое знак_операции простое_логическое).
знак-операции::= AND | OR*

**Вопрос:**
Как тут действовать, ничего не получается. Пытался идти в глубь и уже от туда вычислять это выражение но тоже провал. Провал скорее всего из-за того что не понимаю как это выражение правильно вычислять.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842/195342

Comment: у меня даже есть написанный код на компе. правда переменные все однобуквенные, но это для облегчения понимания.

Comment: В книге Стауструпа есть пример написания синтаксического анализатора выражений. Всё расписано буквально по шагам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как тут действовать

Для вычисления, удобно преобразовать выражение в [обратную польскую запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Хорошая статья на эту тему есть у [Иванова Максима](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/expressions_parsing).

> Обратная польская нотация — это форма записи математических выражений,
> в которой операторы расположены после своих операндов.
>
> Например, следующее выражение: `a + b * c * d + (e - f) * (g * h + i)`
>
> в обратной польской нотации записывается следующим образом:
>
> `a b c * d * + e f - g h * i + * +`

Поясню как вычисляется значение в обратной польской нотации.

- возьмём пустой стек, положим в него `a`, `b` и `c`;
- встречаем оператор `*`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `b`, `c`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `b*c`;
- положим `d` на стек;
- встречаем оператор `*`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `b*c`, `d`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `b*c*d`;
- встречаем оператор `+`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `a`, `b*c*d`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `a+b*c*d`;
- положим `e`, `f` на стек;
- встречаем оператор `-`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `e`, `f`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `e-f`;
- положим `g`, `h` на стек;
- встречаем оператор `*`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `g`, `h`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `g*h`;
- положим `i` на стек;
- встречаем оператор `+`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `g*h`, `i`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `g*h+i`;
- встречаем оператор `*`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `e-f`, `g*h+i`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `(e-f)*(g*h+i)`;
- встречаем оператор `*`;

  - вынимаем из стека 2 значения: `a+b*c*d`, `(e-f)*(g*h+i)`;
  - кладём результат выполнения операции опять на стек: `a+b*c*d+(e-f)*(g*h+i)`;
- обратная польская нотация закончилась, результат на вершине стека.