# Вычисление выражений в интерпретаторе

Tags: c++, хранение-данных, интерпретатор

Пишу интерпретатор с типами переменных int, double, string. Парсер разбивает на элементы языка, но не знаю как правильно реализовать вычислений выражений. Вычисление реализовано как автомат по уровню операции и он в принципе работает, но я храню ответ в float, при присваивании если это int беру только целую часть. Для string я реализовал похожие функции.

У меня следующие вопросы

1. Для каждого типа писать свой обработчик выражений?
2. Если не для каждого типа, то в чем хранить ответ после разбора выражения?
3. Если для каждого типа, то в случае как if,while какой тип выбрать?

Comment: А что вы называете обработчиком выражений ? Парсер должен быть один, который готовит внутреннее представление операций и где то там же в дереве операций сохраняет типы. А уже конечные исполнители операторов конечно должны быть отдельные.

Comment: Наверное имеет смысл разрешать только выражения, где операнды имеют одинаковый тип, и хранить ответ с типом, соответствующим типу операндов выражения.

Comment: для if, while использовать тогда какой использовать тип? у них же может быть как и int так и float? или использовать оба?

Comment: @kaliarty, в if и while только bool должен быть :-) либо что-то что может к нему приводиться, например сравнением с `0`, в этом случае без разницы что сравнивать int или float

Comment: я про это имел ввиду, не правильно выразил мысль

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23842/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так как сам писал такое, то

> Для каждого типа писать свой обработчик выражений?

да, а также возможно и для пар. У меня, к примеру, можно было строку умножать на целое (`"**" * 2 == "****"`), но это зависит от конкретных желаний.

> Если не для каждого типа, то в чем хранить ответ после разбора выражения?

есть чудесный тип [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). И Вам подойдет `std::variant<int, float, std::string>`. Ну или свой тип, с помощью union, но это отдельная история, в которой очень легко выхватить UB.

> Если для каждого типа, то в случае как if,while какой тип выбрать?

тут много вариантов. Можно воспользоваться [get_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if), я пользовался [index](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index). Так как index возвращает число от 0 до кол-ва типов-1 (с примера выше это получается 2), то можно сделать где то так

```
using myval = std::variant<int, float, std::string>;
myval a1,a2;

size_t op_index = a1.index() * 3 + a2.index();

switch(op_index) {
case 0: //int-int
   return myval(a1.get<int>() + a2.get<int>()); // прям так вызываем
case 3*2+1: // string-float
   throw ups();// а так нельзя.
}
```

но если такое лень для каждой операции писать, то можно воспользоваться перегрузками и передавать операцию как параметр в функцию выше.

Второй вариант заключается в том, что делается базовый тип и от него наследуются типы для каждого нужного - то есть, для числа и строки. А потом, с помощью двойной диспетчеризации разбираются операции. Я так пробовал, получилось сильно сильно сложнее и не поддерживаемо.

Comment: странно, вроде бы второй вариант должен быть наоборот проще чем switch по типам 

Comment: я пробовал. правда это было давно-давно, но у меня получалась жуткая связанность между типами.

Comment: @KoVadim ооо, понял, благодарю вас

Comment: Тут не реализовано приоритетов в действиях, это нужно подчёркивать. В упрощенных случаях такое катит. Обычно для парсинга используют "машина Тьюринга", там можно с помощью упорядочивания по приоритету поменять порядок действий. Но там больше кода и метод сложнее.

Comment: почему Вы решили, что там не реализован приоритет? В моем примере совсем нет упоминания о приоритета. О парсинге с помощью "машины Тюринга" я еще не слышал, леворекурсивный парсер или метод сортировочной станции - это да.