# Функции из строки

Tags: c++, строки, функции, процедуры

Делаю программу на с++ по рисованию графиков в консольном приложении. Пока придумала так, что пользователь жмет на одну из "кнопок" и в строку записывается соответствующая функция. Например, при нажатии cos( и 3 выводтся строка "y=cos(3". Все символы ")" доставляются при выборе соответствующего пункта. Есть ли какая-то функция, которая может перенести эту строку в код? По типу eval() в JS. Если нет, как можно реализовать такую схему? Прошу прощение за, возможно, не очень четкую формулировку, пишу как могу.

Comment: [Парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842).

Comment: https://github.com/aslze/asl-calculator

Comment: https://github.com/beltoforion/muparser

Comment: Другими словами, вам нужен простенький интерпретатор выражений, выполняющий разбор строки с выражением и возвращающий его значение. Вы можете написать такую функцию самостоятельно, используя метод рекурсивного спуска. Забейте в гугле "парсер выражений рекурсивный спуск" - найдёте кучу материала по данной теме.